# Multiple values per field in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-entries

- First of all: I know that its really bad style to work with multiple entries in one field, but I did not create the database myself and now I have to work with it. It has around 20000 entries and I really dont want to change it at the moment.
- The table **A** I'm talking about has a column with some ID's, e.G.: `,282,3358,123,`
- Those ID's are matching with the primary keys of some other table **B**. **B** has another column name.
- I want to get those names into my table **A** replacing those ID's
- Example:

**Table B**

```
| ID |      name         |     
+----+-------------------+
|282 |      name_1       |
+----+-------------------+
|3358|      name_2       |
+----+-------------------+
|123 |      name_3       |
```

**Initial Situation TABLE A**

```
 ... |         ID             | ...    
-----+------------------------+-----
 ... |    ,282,3358,123,      | ...
```

**Desired Result for TABLE A**

```
 ... |         ID             | ...    
-----+------------------------+-----
 ... | ,name_1,name_2,name_3, | ...
```

Comment: Is table A a new table?  If so, why not change the structure to something that follows relational database theory - it won't fundamentally change the nature of the problem, but will remove others you'll encounter in the future if you don't...

Comment: Not to mention the fact that if you replace numbers by strings you will run into names like `Smith, Jones` and get confused by the commas.

Comment: @RobBaillie A is an existing Table
@BartFriederichs I'll check the `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Unlucky!  Sounds like you've inherited a beast.  If it's anything like in your power to change the structure of the table, I strongly advise that you do - before you run into some hellish issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way how do deal with my problem. However it's really not recommendable to use multiple entries per field. But if your in a situation like me, where you have to work with such an unrelational schemed database without being allowed to change the scheme, here we are:

```
SELECT [...] ,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( table_B.name SEPARATOR ',' ) FROM table_B 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET ( B.ID , SUBSTRING ( table_A.ID , 2 , length( table_A.ID ) -2 ) ) >0 ) ,
[...]
FROM table_A
```

Some Explanations:

- the `SUBSTRING` is needed in order to remove the "," in the begining of the multiple field entry. E.g.:  `SUBSTRING ( ",282,3358,123," , 2 , length( ",282,3358,123," ) -2 )` results in "282,3358,123"
- the `FIND_IN_SET` method searches a value into a comma separated string list and returns the index of the value. If no value can be found, it returns 0. Thats why I compare the whole string against 0.
- the `GROUP_CONCAT` method concatenates the matching names. As a result it delivers a comma separated string list ==> `name_1,name_2,name_3`

Some Annotations:

- Using this query is very inefficient. That query has to deal with at least #ROWS_IN_TABLE_A * #ROWS_IN_TABLE_B table rows
- Regarding perfomance issues, one should precompute the table and store it into a database (thats what I did).

Answer (score 0):

With just one sql instruction could be very difficult, I'would do a function in MySQL that:

1) Create a cursor with table A
2) Search each value from table B
3) Fill the [new] field with values from B

20000 rows is not too much.